# How do I build Go-SDL on windows?

Tags: sdl, go

Has anyone been successful doing this?

Comment: [This?](http://code.google.com/p/gosdl/)  Or something else?

Comment: @genpfault - If that's the same as https://github.com/banthar/Go-SDL

Comment: I run into problems with `pkg-config` - I can set up the MinGW environment with SDL, but as it is not a package, the Go installer doesn't continue.

Answer (score 1):

It should work by just calling make in the root directory if:
1) You have the GOROOT env variable set
2) You have access to the directory in which go is installed

I had neither. Point one can easily be solved by using gomake instead of make. The problem is that i haven't added the bin directory of the go directory to the root users PATH, so i had to start up a root termianl, export the go bin directory to the PATH and then call gomake in the Go-SDL directory.

My case seems to be pretty special though, but maybe it can help.

Comment: @tm1rbrt What are you trying to build it with? A naked MinGW install? Visual Studio?

Comment: MinGW with gnuMake for windows. I have installed SDL developer files.

Comment: Don't install cygwin to build this - if anything it's worse. the gcc.exe isn't a windows executable, it's a cygwin symbolic link, the cygwin gcc doesn't support -m64 etc. etc.